# how to get decimal format value from json object

Tags: java, android

Im trying to get value from JSONObject. Here is the value in JSONObject.

```
{name: "alice", amount: 2.3}
// name (string), amount (decimal)
```

I was confused of how to get the decimal value from JSONObject. Here is my code. Is my code is correct? i was think that float and decimal is different. I tried to find it, but i did not find it.

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
float myFloatValue = BigDecimal.valueOf(data.getDouble("amount")).floatValue();
```

......

Comment: Why not simply `(float)data.getDouble("amount")`?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when you type a decimal number as 3.6, its interpreted as a double. As a float is less precise than a double, the conversion cannot be performed implicitly.

If you want to create a float, you should end your number with f (i.e.: 3.6f).

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(//your jsonObject);
float myFloatValue=(float)data.getDouble("amount");
```

this works fine

or

Create a POJO class(MyData) with setter and getter. this is better way

```
public class MyData{
private String name;
private Double amount;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Double getAmount() {
    return amount;
}
public void setAmount(Double amount) {
    this.amount = amount;
}
}
```

write this block in you method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JSONObject data = new JSONObject(//your jsonObject);
MyData myData = mapper.readValue(data.toString(),MyData.class);
float myFloatValue=(float)myData.getAmount();
```

now you can have the float value in myFloatValue.

Answer (score 0):

If your amount is in **String** (my best guess its in string else you wont try to convert it into double) try this to get in double.. as

```
  double amt = Double.parseDouble(data.getString("amount"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below work great for me:

```
String data = "{name: \"alice\", amount: 2.3}"; 
org.json.JSONObject object = new org.json.JSONObject(data);
System.out.println(object.getDouble("amount"));
```

Output:

```
run:
2.3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Did you forget to put the JSON data String into the JSONObject constructor?